# what does the oxidation/reduction potential actually mean?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, reduction-potential

**The standard potential of a species is actually its tendency to gain/lose electrons and get reduced/oxidized.** But what I want to understand : 1- Is the standard potential an absolute quantity, or a relative quantity? If relative, relative to what? , 2- what does the value of the standard potential actually mean. For example, the Standard Reduction Potential for lithium at 25 °C is -3.04 volts, does that mean if a slap of lithium lost a 1 Coulomb of electrons, this quantity of electrons would have, according to the definition of electrical potential, an amount of energy equal to 3.04 Joules?

Note: I'm a physics major trying to understand the redox reactions in a battery, and where did the Electrical potential difference caused by the battery came from.

Comment: Describe in the question the explicit summary result of your looking for info or answers before asking. You may then realize during the process you need not to ask any more. It prevents redundant questions/answers and you will not be offered info you (should) already know or do not want.  Well elaborated questions have higher probability to  receive useful answers.  [See the guide How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See also [chem.libretexts.org - Electrochemistry_and_Thermodynamics](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Electrochemistry/Electrochemistry_and_Thermodynamics) and [Gibbs_Energy_and_Redox_Reactions](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Chemistry_-_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/20%3A_Electrochemistry/20.05%3A_Gibbs_Energy_and_Redox_Reactions)

Comment: And yes, your intuition is right. Note the charge versus molar amount proportionality constant F = e . Na as the charge of 1 mol of protons.

Comment: If you're a physics major you should have better understanding of current...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a platinum plate covered by platinum moss is dipped in a beaker containing a $1$ M $\ce{HCl}$ solution. Suppose now that some bubbles of hydrogen gas $\ce{H2}$ are crossing the acidic solution so that some touch the platinum surface. The whole is an electrode called hydrogen electrode.

Suppose now a metallic plate (like zinc $\ce{Zn}$, copper $\ce{Cu}$, etc.) is dipped into another beaker containing the solution of a salt of the corresponding metal (like $\ce{ZnSO4}$, or $\ce{CuSO4}$). This defines a second electrode, called zinc (or copper) electrode.

If now the two ionic solutions of the two beakers are joined by a bridge (for example blotting paper filled with a neutral solution like $\ce{KNO3}$), a voltage, or an electric potential $E$ can be measured with an electronic voltmeter between the platinum electrode of the first cell and the metal plate of the $2$nd electrode. This measured value is called the reduction potential of the ($2$nd) metallic electrode. For example, if the $2$nd electrode is zinc $\ce{Zn}$, the measured potential is $E_{Zn} = -0.76$ V (if the $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ concentration is $1$ M). This value is tabulated and is a reference. If the $2$nd electrode is made of copper $\ce{Cu}$ dipping in a $1$ M $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ solution, the measured reaction potential is $E_{Cu} = +0.34$ V. These values ($-0.76$ V, $+0.34$ V) are considered as constant, as soon as they are measured in a cell containing a hydrogen electrode as first electrode.

But take care. These reduction potentials are only valid when both ionic concentrations are equal to $1$ M. If the ionic concentrations $\ce{[Zn]}$, $\ce{[H^+]}$ and $\ce{[Cu^{2+}]}$ are different from $1$ M, the reduction potentials of $\ce{Zn}$ and $\ce{Cu}$ take the following values :

$\ce{E_{Zn} = -0.76 V + \frac{RT}{2F} ln\frac{[Zn^{2+}]}{[H^+]^2}}$

$\ce{E_{Cu} = +0.34 V + \frac{RT}{2F} ln\frac{[Cu^{2+}]}{[H^+]^2}}$

At $25$°C, the factor $\ce{\frac{RT}{2F}}$ is numerically equal to $0.0295$ V.

Now let's answer your question. The reduction (or standard) potential can be considered as an absolute value, providing it is coupled to a hydrogen electrode, and that the two solutions are $1$ molar.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful!